# decryption algorithm for Adler-32?

Tags: ruby

In my project, I am struggling with decoding an Adler-32 code.
I use the gem 'adler32'. It encrypts strings and returns an 8 digit long hash code. But I'm unable to decrypt it.

Please please help me to decode Adler-32 hash code.

Comment: Adler-32 is a hash algorithm, that is: it's a one-way function. You can't decrypt it output data since it is not encrypted. The algorithm is intended for checksumming, i.e. to ensure that the data you received is the same as the sent data.Typically, you recompute the checksum on the received data and compare it to the checksum provided by the sender. If it matches, the data is likely to be correct, if it differs, either the checksum or the data was changed.

Comment: @HolgerJust , yes i know this one-way-function, but some of online hash code converter are available,they can decrypt adler-32.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't a good fit. We have no idea what your expertise is or what your programming experience is, so helping you would involve a tutorial, which is off-topic. You need to show us what you tried, and then we might be able to help. Read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and "[mcve]".

Comment: The question states: "encrypts strings", but hashes are not encryption, Adler-32 is a checksum.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to "decrypt" Adler-32 because it is not a one-to-one function. In other words, there are multiple inputs that encode to the same output ([here](http://www.leviathansecurity.com/blog/analysis-of-adler32) is some Python code that can generate these collisions). So if you want to decrypt a particular hash code, how would you know which of the many inputs that correspond to that hash code to use?

Even if you're okay with just finding *some* input that corresponds to a hash, you're still out of luck. Because hash functions such as Adler-32 are designed to be [non-invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Non-invertible), meaning you should not be able to easily find an input corresponding to a given output. Doing so would require some significant research of the underlying math, which I have not heard of anyone doing.

All of the online "decryption" sites are most likely just looking up hash codes in a table of [input, output] pairs. Try this: on your own computer hash some long unique phrase, then try to get one of these online sites to decrypt it. I guarantee that if it is able to decrypt it at all, you won't get the same input that you put in.